# Asp.Net MVC and an existing database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework

I have a database. I have a Wcf Service project which is connected to the database and has a data model (.edmx file).
Now I need to add an Asp.Net MVC application.

The tutorials I'm reading say that I should only add the connectionString. But, does that mean that I don't need model classes? Or should I create model classes? Also, the classes in the .edmx file don't extend from DbContext the class.

For example, I have a table named Something in my database which doesn't extend from DbContext.
Do I add a model named SomethingTemplate with all the properties from Something and make it extend from DbContext?

Comment: Are you planning to use Entity Framework **code first** (the `DbContext` you mention seems to indicate as much) ?? If so: please mention that! Also: tag accordingly (use `[ef-code-first]`! Or do you have the EDMX model populated with the tables from the database? But why have an EDMX (database- or model-first approach) **AND** work with a `DbContext` (code-first) .... doesn't make sense...

Comment: @marc_s Yes I have the edmx populated with tables from the database. Well all the tutorial are working with DbContext, I thought I have to work with it also. If I don't use DbContext, should I add model classes?

Comment: @marc_s Ok, but what classes will I put in the model files?

Comment: @marc_s Well the M part of MVC. The MVC application should have its own model, right?

Comment: The EDMX **IS** the model - it's the Entity Data **MODEL** after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a properly designed ASP.NET MVC application the data access layer is abstracted. This means that no matter whether you are using plain ADO.NET, EF, NHibernate or even remote WCF service calls it doesn't really matter.

In the case of WCF if you want to use EF, you will define your data contexts and entities inside this project. The connection string will also be inside the WCF project.

Then in your ASP.NET MVC application you will simply add a service reference to this WCF service which will create a client side proxy allowing you to invoke its methods. It will also import the entities but from the ASP.NET MVC perspective they will be POCOs.

Comment: @Srcee, in your ASP.NET MVC application the domain model classes will be the classes that were generated when you imported the WCF qservice using Add Service Reference. You will of course need view models, but you always need view models in ASP.NET MVC, no matter whether you are using WCF or whatever.

Comment: And what will I put in my model classes? If I have a class Something in the edmx file, do I need to have a class Something as a mode too?

Comment: @Srcee, no, you don't need to. Your Models directory in the ASP.NET MVC application could contain only the view models you need.